# Dew-point temperature and absolute humidity

Tags: meteorology, temperature, humidity

I am looking for a reference (e.g. book, peer-reviewed paper) that asserts that
absolute humidity is "equivalent" to the dew-point temperature.

Such statement should be true, AFAIU. Online, [people say](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-dew-point-a-consequence-of-the-absolute-humidity) [they are the same](https://www.memphisweather.blog/2013/08/how-humid-is-it-why-dew-point-is.html), in scientific publications they look almost linearly related in some range of temperatures [here, figure 4](https://www.naun.org/main/NAUN/mechanics/19-574.pdf), I tested their relation on data I have and their correlation is $ > 0.98$.

But I am unable to find a reference that states the absolute humidity and the dew-point temperature are "equivalent", "highly correlated (under reasonable conditions)", or that "one can serve as a proxy for the other". Please help me find such reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not directly equivalent.  I think the problem is that "absolute humidity" is used to mean both "a measurement of the actual humidity content of the air" ("absolute" as in "non-relative") and, in some sources, "mass of water vapor per unit volume" - which is temperature-dependent as well (using $PV=nRT$ at fixed pressure and mass: $V$ varies with $T$).

I think this [technical note](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/pdf/87878main_H-937.pdf) covers it.  Key points:

- Vapor pressure is a function of dew point alone (Eq. 16 - remaining variables are constants).
- Absolute humidity is a function of vapor pressure *and temperature* (Eq. 3).
- Thus, absolute humidity is a function of both dew point and temperature (Eq. 20).

The reason they appear to be directly related, like in the dataset you looked at, is that $T$ (in Kelvin) only varies by 20% or so in a typical temperature range (e.g., -20 to +40 C = 253 to 313 K), so it doesn't affect things that much.

That technical note does work as a citation for dew point being an absolute measurement of humidity, since it corresponds directly to vapor pressure in Eq. 16.